# How can I select a specific tag in two different HTML structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two different HTML structure and I cannot change them. Now I need to write a jQuery code to get the `href` attribute of one specific `<a>` in them. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.myclass', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(e);
  
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  console.log(url);
  
  $(this).closest('li').css('background-color','#f1f1f1');
})
```

```css
li{
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

a{
  display:block;
}

.myclass{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML1:

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">sth</a>
    <span>something</span>
    <a class="myclass" href="./my/path">link</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<hr />

HTML2:

<ul>
  <li class="myclass">
    <a href="./my/path">
    <span>something</span>
    </a>
    <div>sth</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Ok, let me explain. I want two things happen when the user clicks on `.myclass` element: *(as you see, `.myclass` element is different in two HTML structures)*

- Setting a pale gray color to the background of `li`.
- Printing the `href` value of the link in the console.

My current code works correctly for the first HTML structure *(but not for the second one)*.

---

**Note:** For the second one, jQuery code should look like this:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.myclass', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(e);

  var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  console.log(url);

  $(this).css('background-color','#f1f1f1');
})
```

See? I've added `find('a')` *(there is always one `<a>` in the second kind of HTML)* and removed `closest('li')`.

Anyway, how can I write one jQuery code instead of both above?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to test where current element is anchor and keep using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to target LI element.

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

```
$(document).on('click', '.myclass', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    var url;
    if ($(this).is('a')) {
        url = $(this).attr('href');
    } else {
        url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    }
    console.log(url);

    $(this).closest('li').css('background-color', '#f1f1f1');
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.myclass', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(e);
  var url;
  if ($(this).is('a')) {
    url = $(this).attr('href');
  } else {
    url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  }
  console.log(url);

  $(this).closest('li').css('background-color', '#f1f1f1');
})
```

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

.myclass {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML1:

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">sth</a>
    <span>something</span>
    <a class="myclass" href="./my/path">link</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<hr /> HTML2:

<ul>
  <li class="myclass">
    <a href="./my/path">
      <span>something</span>
    </a>
    <div>sth</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

However It would be cleaner to use separate event handler

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.myclass', function(e){  
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
})
$(document).on('click', 'li.myclass', function(e){  
  var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
})
```

Comment: I think `$(this).closest('li').css('background-color', '#f1f1f1');` should be dynamic too. Because in the second HTML structure, no need to `closest('li')`. Am I right?

Comment: @MartinAJ, Don't you want to change the background of `li`? as `closest()` start looking for matches the traversing up so there is no harm in using it

Comment: I **want**. But in the second HTML structure `$(this)` is `li`, so no need to `.closest('li')`. Am I right? And I'm surprised how your snippet code works correctly.

Comment: Oh, ok upvote. Just to be sure, you mean in this case, both `$(this).closest('li').` and `$(this).` are the same?

Comment: @MartinAJ, if `$(this).is('li')`  then `$(this).closest('li')`. and `$(this).` will refer to same DOM element

Answer (score 2):

This would be cleaner using a css rule for the background

```js
$(document).on('click', '.myclass', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(e);
  var $el = $(this),
    //if this is <a> tag use it for href, otherwise find it
    $link = $el.is('a') ? $el : $el.find('a:first'),
    url = $link.attr('href');
    
  $el.closest('li').toggleClass('active');
  console.log(url);
 
})
```

```css
li{
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

a{
  display:block;
}

.myclass{
    cursor: pointer;
}

li.active, .myclass.active{
  background-color:#f1f1f1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML1:

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">sth</a>
    <span>something</span>
    <a class="myclass" href="./my/path">link</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<hr />

HTML2:

<ul>
  <li class="myclass">
    <a href="./my/path">
    <span>something</span>
    </a>
    <div>sth</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear about the problem at hand, but tried this

```
$(document).on('click', '.myclass', function(e){
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    var x='';
    if(evt.target.tagName=="LI")
    {
        x = $(this).find('a.myclass').attr('href');
        $(this).css('background-color', '#f1f1f1');
    } 
    else if(evt.target.tagName=="A")
    {
        x =  $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).parent("li").css('background-color', '#f1f1f1');
    }
    console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: target won't be same as `this` when click on any children. Also first example shows an `<a>` that isn't the href wanted and would get wrong url output

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in a number of ways ranging from checking what type of tag it is, all the way to applying data attributes and then checking them against that what we have on the clicked class.

For this example, we're checking if it has a 'href' tag.

I have left the separate background colour setters in each if() in case you wish to change them to different values at some point.

Here's my take on it:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

  $('.myclass').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
   var url;

    if($(this).attr("href")) { //WE check if the "href" attribute exists
      //Found, it must be an link
      url = $(this).attr('href');
      console.log(url);
      $(this).closest('li').css('background-color','#f1f1f1');

    } else {
      //Not found
       url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
       console.log(url);
       $(this).css('background-color','#f1f1f1');

    }

  });

});
```